# Difficulties with complex numbers and complex planes

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the general form of a complex number $z$ such that:
>   i) $z^2$ is a real number (i.e. $\operatorname{Im} z^2 = 0$);
>   ii) $z^2$ is a purely imaginary number (i.e. $\operatorname{Re} z^2 = 0$);
>   iii) $z^2 = \bar z$.

I'm not sure how to tackle this question

For i), I wrote
$$\operatorname{Im}(z^2) = (z^2-z'^2)/2$$
and I then get stuck and I don't know how to rearrange the formula in a helpful way.

Comment: Please edit your question with LaTeX syntax using $....$. It would be nice if you would not use links, as they might expire.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$.  Then, $z^2=(x^2-y^2)+i2xy$.  So, if the imaginary part is zero, then

$$xy=0\implies \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x=0 \,\,\text{or}\,\, y=0}$$

If the real part of $z^2$ is zero, then

$$x^2-y^2=0\implies \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y=\pm x}$$

And finally, if $z^2=\bar z$, then

$$x^2-y^2=x\,\,\text{and}\,\,2xy=-y\implies\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{ (x,y)=(0,0)\,,(1,0)\,,(-1/2,\sqrt{3}/2)\,,(-1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

use the polar form $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$ and your problem becomes simpler since $z^2=\rho^2 e^{i2\theta}$ ....

Answer (score 0):

In addition to thinking about this algebraically, you can think about it geometrically.

Do you know about the [Argand Plane](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgandDiagram.html)? This is a way of thinking about complex numbers as points on a 2D plane. (Or as elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$, if that's familiar to you). The $x$-axis is the real axis and the $y$-axis is the imaginary axis. Each point in 2D space (and each complex number) makes a certain angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis and has a certain magnitude $r$. The angle is called the *argument* and the magnitude is called the *phase*, don't ask me why.

[image: The Argand Plane]

(Picture stolen from my link). That's all it takes to uniquely specify a complex number. Here's a question that's fun and important -- given a complex number in $x + iy$ form, how would you find its phase and its argument?

But actually you don't need to know that to answer these problems. When you multiply two complex numbers, you **add their angles** and **multiply their magnitudes**.

For example, if you multiply $i \times i$, the result has magnitude $1 \times 1 = 1$ and angle $90° + 90° = 180°$. The answer is the number that has angle $180°$ and lies on the unit circle, and that number is $-1$.

So to answer your first question, we just have to think "which numbers, if I rotate them by themselves, will land on the real axis?" Clearly $1$ and all positive real numbers will do this (their angle is $0°$, so they don't go anywhere when rotated). Also $-1$ and all negative real numbers, since $180° + 180° = 360° = 0°$. With a bit more thought, we can see that $i$ and all positive imaginary numbers will land on the negative axis when squared, since $90° + 90° = 180°$. And with a bit more, all negative imaginary numbers, since $270° + 270° = 540° = 180°$. Personally I think about algebra when I think about $i \times i = -1$ and $-i \times -i = -1$, but it can be enlightening to see how it works out in this way as well.

For your second question, we're looking for angles that add to $90°$ and $270°$. So we've got $45°$ and $135°$, but also $225° + 225° = 90°$ and $315° + 315° = 270°$. I got those by adding $45°$ to $180°$ and to $270°$.

For your last question, the complex conjugate of a number should just be its reflection across the $x$-axis (since you're negating the imaginary part). So you're looking for which rotates itself to its own reflection.